# DrawElements and BadExec

Tags: objective-c, opengl

While i am using the following lines i keep having a consistent BAD_EXEC:

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, [drawObjectTmp getVertices]);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, [drawObjectTmp getVerticesSizeArray], GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, [drawObjectTmp getVertexIndices]);
```

Where `getVertexindices` returns an array defined as (GLushort*)  and `getsizesSizeArray` returns its size. I have crosschecked the context of the array; it does have the right values.

If i replace the array by the following, it works fine:

```
static const GLfloat cubeVertices[] = {
    -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
    1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
    1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
};
```

What exactly i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you haven't enabled other arrays (like TexCoord, or Color, or Normal array)?

Are you sure getVertexIndices doesn't contain vertex index that is outside of getVertices returned array?

Are you sure getVertices returns pointer to memory that is not deallocated during glDrawElements?

Comment: For the 1st question: if i change the pointer array by the static array, it works fine. Also i have no other array enabled which could conflict with that one. For the 2nd question: i use vertices and indices directly exported from Blender 3D; so i suppose it should be okay. But do you see , this situation could occur still ? For your third question: which condition could an array be deallocated during the execution time of drawelements? at least in the current code, the array gets deallocated when the app closes only...

Comment: Well your function could be returning pointer to local array on the stack. That's a common mistake. Try checking the index values to verify that they all have valid values.

Comment: I understand. If i print with NSLog, the vertex indices show the right values. Also the (GLushort*) array is a data member of the drawobject tmp; with no similar local variable which could conflict with its data.

Comment: You should really post more code of how you load, store and render data. Otherwise we are playing guessing game.

Comment: I have fixed the BAD_EXEC. In fact you were right : the vertice indexes were incorrect. The story is when Blender 3D exports the objects to OBJ format, it starts the vertex indexes by 1; not 0. As soon as i have modified the indexes to start at 0 it works fine. Big thanks for this very helpful question ! :) :) :)